# make a class convertible to another class vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, listview, listviewitem

Is it possible to make my custom `item` class so that I can put it straight into a listviewitem? 
What I mean is a listview and I want to be able to do Listview.items(0) = `Item`

Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your class *derive* from `ListViewItem`

```
Public Class MyItem
    Inherits ListViewItem

    ....

End Class
```

This allows you to use `MyItem` in all places where a `ListViewItem` is accepted.